# CORS POST fail with AWS HTTP API Gateway + Lambda integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have scoured over 25 SO posts about this but cannot find a solution to my problem. I have an API Gateway with an HTTP API + route that utilizes a Lambda function integration. From SO posts and AWS documentation, I am reading conflicting information:

1. From [the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html), I see

> If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway automatically sends a response to preflight OPTIONS requests, even if there isn't an OPTIONS route configured for your API. For a CORS request, API Gateway adds the configured CORS headers to the response from an integration.

> If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway ignores CORS headers returned from your backend integration.

This is exactly what I did; I configured my CORS as follows:
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O48G.png)

However, I still get the errors:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://domain.execute-api.aws-region.amazonaws.com/dev/upload' from
 origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is 
present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the 
request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

From Cloudwatch, I can see the requests being sent to the API, but for some reason the header isn't properly configured. I do not understand this because I thought API Gateway should handle OPTIONS pre-flight requests for HTTP APIs. I cannot find out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue, the preflight response had no CORS headers. I noticed that the preflight request included the header: `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type`

As soon I added `Content-Type` to the list of `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` in the HTTP API configuration it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway automatically sends a
> response to preflight OPTIONS requests

I think that rule doesn't work for the POST method, because I met the same issue. Then I tried to add an OPTIONS route manually, everything works well.

Route image

[image: 1]