# AWS API Gateway HTTP proxy with JWT authorizer and CORS settings acts strangely and possibly insecure

Tags: jwt, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have an API gateway acting as secure HTTP proxy calling a private HTTP load balancer inside a VPC for `/api/{proxy+}` route. There is a JWT authorizer, and some CORS settings. All APIs work as expected when tested in Postman. I am experiencing what seems nonsensical and confusing behavior of the gateway when APIs are called from a browser, making me doubt my sanity and leaving my system somewhat less secure.

What I found is that if both CORS and JWT authorizer are configured, the API gateway responds to browser's preflight request (without Authorization header and JWT token) with configured CORS headers, but also a 401 Unauthorized status. This is interpreted by the browser as failed preflight request, so the API call itself also fails due to CORS issue.

Since there is no way to make the browser send Authorization header in CORS preflight request, I had to configure another route for `/api/{proxy+}` just for OPTIONS method, which will call the same integration (private HTTP load balancer), but without the JWT authorizer.

This works, but now the confusing part. I can see in logs that the backend API is getting the OPTIONS request from the API gateway, and I don't understand why is it doing it.

On one hand, this is exactly what is expected from having an unauthorized route for OPTIONS method.

On the other hand, [AWS API gateway documentation for HTTP APIs and CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-cors.html) says explicitly:

> If you configure CORS for an API, API Gateway automatically sends a response to preflight OPTIONS requests, even if there isn't an OPTIONS route configured for your API. For a CORS request, API Gateway adds the configured CORS headers to the response from an integration.

But if the above was true, I would have not needed to configure OPTIONS route, and the preflight requests would have worked. There is a caveat on that page about $default routes, but this does not apply to my setup.

My issue is that in the current configuration, the API gateway would forward any HTTP OPTIONS request to a URL starting with /api/ to the backend without any authorization, which is concerning.

I'm not sure if this is a real issue, since OPTIONS request handling at the backend is cheap, and a major DDoS attack is probably going to be stopped by AWS anyway before I get an astronomic bill for billions API gateway calls. However, it also seems entirely pointless, as the response to OPTIONS from the backend is completely ignored by the gateway.

Should I be concerned with my backend security, and is there an explanation for the behaviour of the API gateway? Also, is there a different method for handling CORS requests and JWT authorization at the API gateway level that does not have such problem?

An answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73321244/6263021) seems to imply that I'm not the only person experiencing that, but there was no further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

After some further deliberation I concluded that I am not comfortable with the expose of the backend and looked for other options.

I came up with two:

1. Switch from HTTP to REST-style API gateway and configure it to return a mock response to OPTIONS request, thus protecting the backend. Mock responses are not available in HTTP API gateways.
2. Add a rule on the private ALB to return a static response to requests with OPTIONS method.

I implemented option 2, and stopped seeing OPTIONS requests reaching the backend, so I guess it's as good as it gets.

That said, still looking for insights into what seems counterintuitive behavior of the API gateway.